# React Native | Firebase Firestore | Storing user data only after pressing twice

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

**What I expect:** When I press the text "sign up" once it will both create a user in firebase auth and then create a user in firestore with the single property.

**What is actually happening:** When I press the text "Sign Up" it immediately creates a user in firebase auth, but then it only creates a user in firestore with the property once I press either the username field, the password field, or the Sign Up button for a second time.

**I suspect:** That this has to do something with promises and my nested .then's but can't figure out why it is operating this way; seems really strange.

Sample code:

```
import React from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/firestore";

const Screen = () => {
  const firestore = firebase.firestore();

  const writeUserData = uid => {
    const docRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
    docRef
      .set({
        example_property
      })
      .then(item =>
        console.log("successfully added user to the collection" + item)
      )
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.submitButton}
        onPress={() =>
          firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(userObj => writeUserData(userObj.user.uid))
            .catch(error => {
              var errorCode = error.code;
              var errorMessage = error.message;
              console.log("errorCode: " + errorCode);
              console.log("errorMessage: " + errorMessage);
            })
        }
      >
          <Text>Sign Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Maybe in your original sample, at the time of initial firing there was no user yet?  See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user  specifically the section about how the user can be null, and listening for authState.  But congrats on solving your problem!

Comment: Thank for the advice @Tedskovsky, I had considered that but the app would previously do nothing for minutes at a time and then immediately create the document once I pressed a selector again. :)

Comment: No problem.  Also, I noticed a typo in your code above: `userObj.User.uid`  (needs a capital U")

Answer (score 1):

It now works that I've removed the anonymous function from the .then in writeUserData. See here:

```
const writeUserData = uid => {
    const docRef = firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`);
    docRef
      .set({
        example_property
      })
      .then(console.log("successfully added user"))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```